# Raspberrypi python display image from memory

Tags: python, image, camera, raspberry-pi

the task is folowing: capture the frame from Picamera on external event (GPIO) and display it on the screen.

methods used:

1. PIL image.show() - make temporary file and use external viewer, I need from memory.
2. Opencv cv.imshow() - freeze window with image after several sequenced events. I have played with delays it still freeze.
3. UPD: Gdk Window with image also freeze after several events but it is not freeze if GLib timer event call update, but not GPIO's handler.

Could you suggest any method to complete this task ?

Comment: Why do you need from memory exactly please?

Comment: Frequency of event  aprox 1Hz. So to avoid flash memory rewrites and make it as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create a small RAMdisk which is nice and fast and avoids wear on your SD card. Write the image to that and display it with `feh` or similar:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/ramdisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=4M tmpfs /media/ramdisk

df /media/ramdisk
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs               4096     0      4096   0% /media/ramdisk
```

Then start a Python script updating your images.

---

The initial script might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a couple of useful variables
MNTPNT="/media/ramdisk"
IMGNAM="$MNTPNT/image.ppm"

# Make ramdisk and mount
sudo mkdir -p /media/ramdisk 2> /dev/null
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=4M tmpfs /media/ramdisk 2> /dev/null

# Create initial empty image to display with ImageMagick or any other means
convert -size 800x600 xc:black -depth 8 "$IMGNAM"

# Get 'feh' started in "Slideshow mode" in the background
feh --title "Monitor" -D 0.5 "$IMGNAM" "$IMGNAM" &

# Now start Python script with image name
./monitor.py "$IMGNAM"
```

Then the Python script `monitor.py` might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, sys, time
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from random import randint

# Pick up parameters
filename = sys.argv[1]

# Create initial image and drawing handle
w, h = 800, 600
im = Image.new("RGB",(w,h),color=(0,0,0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

# Create name of temp image in same directory
tmpnam = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), "tmp.ppm") 

# Now loop, updating the image 100 times
for i in range(100):
   # Select random top-left and bottom-right corners for image
   x0 = randint(0,w)
   y0 = randint(0,h)
   x1 = x0 + randint(10,250)
   y1 = y0 + randint(10,250)
   # Select a random colour and draw a rectangle
   fill = (randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))
   draw.rectangle([(x0,y0),(x1,y1)], fill=fill)
   # Save image to a temporary file, then rename in one immutable operation...
   # ... so that 'feh' cannot read a half-saved image
   im.save(tmpnam)
   os.rename(tmpnam,filename)
   time.sleep(0.3)
```

[image]

In essence, all your application has to do is:

```
 while true:
   ... generate new image ...
   im.save(tmpnam)
   os.rename(tmpnam,filename)
```

If you remove the `--title "monitor"` from the `feh` command, you will see it is just iterating through a list of 2 images, that both happen to be the same image. The images are swapped every 0.5 seconds, without flashing. You can change that if you want. If you don't want it continuously alternate between the two for some reason you can make the delay much bigger, and send a `SIGUSR1` to `feh` (`os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)`) to make it switch whenever you update the image.

Comment: I have tried. Popen, does not open window. Will it refresh image after writing several times different images into stdin?

Comment: need ,shell=True. It do not refresh image after being written to same window twice or more. So solution is not usefull because kill and restore process is too slow. First solution can update only 1Hz I need little bit more and syncronized. Also is slow.

Comment: Creazy script! will try maybe... feh refresh rate is 1 per second so it ignore 0.5 and make 1 I need more . I have tied to make image viewwer using Gdk library. And you know ? Same bug ! It hangs after 10 or so external events.Main program with GPIO handler is working and GDK window is freazed.

Comment: Do you know other way of serving external events rather then GPIO ?

Comment: The image changes twice per second on my machine with `-D 0.5`

Comment: I think it is affect on GDI window. Or ... maybe (another silly idea) I need to pass something like context into GPIO handler or finish handler some specal way.